# Why did current increase when voltage decreased?

Tags: power-electronics, basic, home-installation

I was taking a short course on home electronics (mostly just how to safely change sockets, switches, and bulbs) and the instructor told an anecdote about how when the energy company accidentally reduced the voltage supplied to his block of houses, there were problems because the current *increased* as a result.

How could that be? Clearly there was something going on not covered by the basic "Ohm's law for idealized resistors"  we covered in the course, which would have predicted that currents went down, but I don't know what, and I couldn't really get a good answer out of our instructor.

Answer (score 11):

Instantaneous increase in current with lower input voltage is only  possible with power electronics with regulation. For example a TV will adjust the duty cycle of the SMPS to keep all DC rail voltages the same as before, therefore SMPSes will draw more current as input voltage is decreasing. Linear loads such as incandescent lamps, regular stoves and similar does not.

Average (over a longer period of time) current will increase with linear and motor loads with thermostats. Your oven or refrigerator for instance will appear to draw less (instantaneous) current as voltage decreases, but the thermostat will compensate to keep average power the same as before, so the average current has increased (longer on-time and higher duty cycle).

As you can see, regulation is the key word. Without it, less current. With it, more current.

Comment: At a lower voltage, you need more current to provide the same power. So any device that is designed to provide the same power regardless of voltage will draw more current as the voltage drops.

Comment: @davidschwartz and winny thanks for the clear answers. Are the mechanisms used to achieve constant power supply / regulation easily described / classified Ina way an interested layman could follow or read up about?

Comment: And most importantly, is there any hint on common household applicances whether they act as constant resistors or as constant power drawers?

Comment: @Bananach The basic question to ask is "is anything being controlled here". For example, a basic kettle or toaster isn't controlling temperature, it just heats the water/bread resistively until some simple mechanical switch turns the heating element off. But an oven or a fridge has a temperature feedback mechanism that is aiming for a constant average temperature. So it needs to supply constant power to the temperature regulation bit. Start with asking "what's being controlled and how" and that will guide you.

Answer (score 6):

Well, very few devices are actually perfect ohmic resistors!

For example, your electronic devices (PCs, laptop chargers, TVs…) will use some specific power – and the switch-mode supply that drives these devices will have to get that power from the grid. So, if your laptop needs 50 W, and your grid voltage was, say, 230 V, then the current would be roundabout 50 W / 230 V = 0.22 A; but if it was, say, only 210 V, the current would be 50 W / 210 V = 0.24 A.

The large consumers in private households are typically, however, pretty resistive: ovens, heaters, stoves, kettles, boilers, hairdriers, and back in the day incandescent lamps.

Here's the story about these: while they pretty much are perfect ohmic resistors, their resistance depends on temperature – the resistance rises when the thing gets warmer. And that's mightily practical: your 2 kW heater doesn't need any special circuitry to make sure it doesn't burn when there's 10% higher voltage than expected; the moment it gets warmer, its resistance rises, the current through it drops, and the things becomes self-stabilizing.

Same is true, of course, for lowering of voltage: the heater at first doesn't get as hot as quickly, you would think, but matter of fact, as long as its cold, its resistance is higher, and it has, for as long as it heats up, simply a higher power.

Now, do I buy the story that you were told? There must be more to it. A power company can't just arbitrarily reduce voltage in a substation. These are fixed transformers, and there's not an intern who drives around with a truck and randomly swaps a couple hundred kilograms in copper windings, having little accidents on the way :)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge lowering the voltage (within the specs) was an "accepted" way to reduce the load in former times. E.g. the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownout_(electricity) states "Intentional brownouts are used for load reduction in an emergency, or to prevent a total grid power outage due to high demand.[3]"

Comment: yes, but that's basically grid-wide; how would you do that for a street?

Comment: Power grid operators have some ways to actively (re-)balance sub grids. I am just guessing at this point but tap changing transformer might be involved.

Comment: There was a bit to the story I didn't tell because I didn't understand: something about a new building being built to closely to a transformer

Comment: Even with resistive coils which, as you describe, are to a degree self-regulating, the lower voltage leads to lower currents in the equilibrium state (with light bulbs, I'd guess, within a second). Yes, the equilibrium current is not proportionally lower, but it is still lower.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "passively regulated resistance" besides the active SMPS, even if it can't explain the full inversion of the power current relation

Comment: @ChristianB. And it works well if the power is mostly being used for heating (almost always resistive loads) or cooling (motors aren't purely resistive, but they draw less current with less voltage). When half the country turns on their kettles at half-time in a soccer game (the famous UK worst-case scenario), browning out works. But most electronic equipment works to keep the required *power* for the equipment, so dropping voltage increases its current draw. Usually this isn't a problem though, unless you're looking at an AWS data centre or something like that.

Comment: @Bananach just guessing: maybe they build a new house (i.e. added a new load) very close to the substation/transformer (i.e. voltage source). Then they realized that the voltage specs was excessed, thus they lowered the voltage in that sub circuit. The lower voltage lead to higher current uptake for further away loads (i.e. loads with higher Raccess), which in turns lead to increased voltage drop over the lines, which leads to a nasty self enforcing power drop. But this is just a wild guess.

Comment: @ChristianB.... and lowering the voltage is easy because they can change the taps on the transformer, of course.

Comment: Many big resistive loads are constant *power*, averaged over long enough timescales - lower current through your oven's element means it runs for longer to reach and maintain the same temperature, hairdryers take longer to do their job, etc. Over many devices at busy periods that averages out to higher current despite each device's instantaneous current being lower.

Comment: Correction: as long as it's cold, its resistance is *lower*.

Answer (score 6):

My family lived in a house with low voltage for a while.  At some point, the meter itself burned out and the power company came and fixed the low voltage problem. The house was at the end of a very long run - it was on a farm so far out in the sticks you needed binoculars to see if the neighbors were at home.

We had problems with the well pump motor burning out (replaced at least twice), with the motor in the clothes washer burning out, and the heating elements in the oven, the stove, and the clothes dryer.

The motors burned out because the motor speed depends on the voltage. If the voltage is too low, they stay at low speed.  At low speed they draw more current than at full speed.

The heating elements burned out because they couldn't heat up fast enough. At full voltage, the elements get hot rather quickly. They are then turned on and off to maintain the temperature. When the voltage is low, they take longer to get hot so they draw high current for a longer time. Heating elements also draw less current when they are hot than when they are cold. That means they were drawing more current for longer than they were designed for.  Mostly what happened was that the plugs on the heating elements got too hot from the high current. The connectors failed, requiring a replacement of the heating element (pins burned through) as well as the socket in the device (oven, stove, dryer).

My dad told the power company that the problem was low voltage. They didn't believe him because he wasn't an electrician and he wasn't using a calibrated voltmeter.

One night in the middle of a very hot summer, the meter itself burned out. We had the air conditioner running. It had run all day and on into the night because it was so hot.

The current it drew was enough that something in the meter box blew. Either the connectors to the meter or the main fuse, I don't know.

My dad put jumpers around whatever it was, and got the power company to finally come out the next day.

Their own measurements proved that the voltage in the house was very low, so they did something to the transformer on the power line pole outside the house to raise the voltage - and they fixed the meter, of course.

Comment: great. Now I need to wait two days to award a bounty to this answer.

Comment: You give three examples: meters, motors, and heating. (A) heating: you say it draws current longer. That makes sense. However, does it draw a proportionally lower current longer, or does it draw an equal or higher current longer? If the former, why does that lead to more total plug heat, if the latter what mechanism does it use to increase current, i.e., auto regulate it's resistance?:(B) motor: you say "at low speed they draw more current than at full speed". Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: (C) the meter: presumably the current this is drawing is just a function of the current the other two examples (and maybe more) are drawing?

Comment: And most importantly, is there any hint on common household applicances whether they act as constant resistors or as constant power drawers?

Answer (score 5):

There are an increasing number of devices using universal-input power supplies - typically 100 - 240 V AC, 50 - 60 Hz. These rectify the mains to create an internal high-voltage DC supply which is then chopped by a switching transistor feeding a transformer to give, usually, a regulated DC voltage. In effect, these are "constant power" power supplies.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMVuA4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A very sketchy block diagram of a switched mode power supply (SMPS). The output voltage is monitored and a control signal is fed back to the switcher to increase or decrease the amount of power fed through the transformer to maintain the output.*

Meanwhile the power equation, \$ P = VI \$ means that the power supply's input current is \$ I = \frac PV \$ so as voltage decreases current must increase to provide the required output voltage and current.

Equipment likely to exhibit this behaviour includes all electronics (TV, computer, non-incandescent lamps, motor speed controllers, etc.).

Comment: At which part of your diagram does the "constant power"ness emerge? E.g., would that effect still be observable without the output rectifier, or without the switcher?

Comment: @Bananach, thanks for seeking clarification. I've updated the block diagram to show the feedback and control. If the output voltage (and hence the power) falls the switcher control pulses will be longer ...

Comment: @Bananach It's actually a function of the control logic - they can behave with almost any I/V curve you want, since the control logic controls the output voltage as well. If it stabilizes the output voltage (the usual design) of course you'll get a constant power, but you could also make the output proportional to the input, giving a constant resistance behaviour, or inversely proportional if you're a madman.

Answer (score 4):

A simple and practical reason: MOST electrical appliances are powered to get **some pre-determined work done** and not for the sake of powering them (Christmass lighs are a notable exception).

A water heater is expected to heat some amount of water up to some temperature. Its heating element has pretty much ohmic behavior and its current and voltage are proportional.

You lower the voltage to 1/2 of the rated one (just to ease the calculation, most appliances fail to work at voltage this low, but the rule still holds). The current also gets 1/2 of the rated current.

Now the power of the heating element is only **1/4 of the rated power**, but you are not OK showering with cold water so now you **wait 4 times longer** to get the same hot water.

Your water heater ran at half of the current, but 4 times longer. The current averaged over some long period (e.g. week) is **2 times higher**.

It is not only the water heater. Space heaters, water pumps, washing machines, car chargers, etc... all run until the work is done and for some use cycle they need a certain amount of kWh to get the work done. **The power consumption, averaged over some extended period and over many homes, is more or less constant** (for constant external conditions).

**You lower the voltage, they all run longer.**

If you sum the current over the whole neighborhood, the overall effect is that when you lower the voltage, the grid pulls more current because many different devices now work longer in order to get whatever they are expected to do, done.

It is actually somewhat worse, because at lower voltage (and higher current) the whole grid is less efficient (more power is lost in wires) and this is compensated by pulling even more current from the power source.

Then again, **the current in a modern power grid does not increase instantly in response to the lowered voltage**. If at some moment you lower the voltage by 10%, chances are that you will see like 5-7% lower current right away and slow (at a timescale of hour or so) increase above the previous value.

---

Some modern appliances (e.g pretty much any electronics 1995+, appliances boasting "inverter" in their name, etc...) internally switch on/of some circuit in order to get exactly the amount of power needed (this is what "switching power supply" is all about). **These devices will readily raise the current in response to lowered power voltage just in order to perform** up to their specs.

---

And some history.

Many decades ago, when most of the domestic energy consumption was incandescent lighting, lowering the grid voltage actually did decrease the current. Most people did not have spare lamps to turn on in response to the dimmer light and no one used light longer because it was dimmer (chances were that if the light was not enough for whatever they were doing, they would just give up and turn off their light).

Answer (score 3):

Not everything is a resistor.

Quite a lot of the electronic devices in the average home, from televisions to computers to even modern LED lights, are powered by one type or another of switching power supply. A switching power supply acts like a constant-*power* load, so a reduced voltage causes it to draw more current to compensate.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers - many types of AC motors will draw more current as voltage decreases. This is the cause behind many motor "burn outs". The fridge, aircon motors would be a likely candidate for increasing current draw in a domestic environment.

Contrary to expectation, motor speed is in most cases not related to input voltage, but is a function solely of construction (number of poles) and input frequency.

Some grid level transformers have adjustable tapping (output voltage), so the story is credible.

Source: former electrician.